# Nativescript, Unable to make changes on device. error is: cannot read property 'startsWith' of null

Tags: android, windows, command-line, nativescript

I ran `tns run android` in my Windows 10 Command prompt with administrator privelleges.

Upon execution i get this error

```
C:\Users\Work\tns-station\Hello>tns run android
```

`Skipping node_modules folder! Use the syncAllFiles option to sync files from this folder.
Searching for devices...
Copying template files...
Unable to apply changes on device: 192.168.28.102:5555. Error is: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null.`

Please what is the problem. 
Note: "I ran this command in my apps directory".

Comment: Try `tns platform remove android` & `tns platform add android` before hitting `tns run android`. It just cleans up platforms directory.

Comment: When i run tns platform add android it shows "Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null"

Comment: Did you try reinstalling nativescript global module? `npm install -g nativescript@latest`

Comment: I just did its still not working. It still shows the error "Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null"

Comment: Can you execute `tns run android --log trace` and paste the log in order to get more info about the error?

Comment: could be proxy issue. Have you tried npm config get proxy ?

Comment: I did `tns run --log trace` here are the logs: Error in source while trying to extract stream from tns-android@5.2.1. Error is TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null
Unable to apply changes on device: 192.168.28.102:5555. Error is: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null.``

Comment: Guys i need your help please

Answer (score 0):

Might be unrelated, but I had the same error message and it turned out that my HTTPS_PROXY environment variable was incorrect (incorrectly started with an '=' in my case).

Check that the value of the proxy variables are correct.

To help narrow down the issue, run with the "--log trace" and if you are able, check the value returned by `getProxyUri` with the getAgent method within `\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\agent.js`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I would appreciate if you provide the exact command to check for the proxy value. I am kind of like a newbie.

Comment: Depends on the shell you use. Bash would be "echo $HTTPS_PROXY" or command prompt "echo %HTTPS_PROXY%"

Comment: Also try the lowercase version of that